# How to show a Views Slideshow block on a basic page with images from only one node

Tags: views

I have a page with an URL like this: example.com/albums
On this page i'd like to show a Views Slideshow with all images from the latest album node and JCarousel pager items.
This Slideshow would for example show all the pictures from an album node that was added yesterday. When a newer album node is added, this one will be displayed in the slideshow.

The goal is to have a featured album slideshow, show at the top of the page of for example an event that took place yesterday.

The problem i'm having is that my Slideshow and JCarousel is showing the images from **every** album node, instead of just the ones from the latest one.

Normally I would add a Slideshow on the node page itself, so that I could use the Contextual Filter -> Content: nid -> default value -> ID from URL.
But I cannot get the ID from the URL, because the Slideshow is added as a block to my /albums page with no ID in the URL.

Setting the pager to only show '1' item is not an option either, because then the slideshow will only show one image. When I set it to 'Display all items' it shows all images from every album node again though.

Is there a different way to get only the data from one unique node without looking at the ID in the URL?

View image if it helps:
[image: View settings]

Thumbnails is used as pager for the slideshow
Content: Sfeerimpressies is the images field.
Both have 'Display all values in the same row' unchecked.